# Issue w Semaphore in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, semaphore

I'm trying to implement a Semaphore that limits the concurrent processes for a task that I'm trying to carry out. However, I'm not getting the behaviour that I expect, and even worse, it is not consistent.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def test_print():
    Sema.acquire()
    print("starting!")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("ending!")
    Sema.release()


concurrency = 3
Sema = multiprocessing.Semaphore(concurrency)
processList = []

if __name__ = "___main__":
    for _ in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target = test_print)
        p.start()
        processList.append(p)
```

I expect

```
starting!
starting!
starting!
ending!
ending!
ending!
starting!
starting!
starting!
ending!
ending!
ending!
starting!
starting!
starting!
ending!
ending!
ending!
starting!
ending!
```

but I get on my Linux server

```
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
```

and on my Macbook:

```
starting!
starting!
starting!
starting!
starting!
starting!
starting!
starting!
starting!
starting!
ending!
ending!
ending!
ending!
ending!
ending!
ending!
ending!
ending!
ending!
```

Any help is appreciated, in particular if I am having some conceptual misunderstanding of what the Semaphore is doing (I'm a newbie to multiprocessing). Thanks a lot!

Comment: The reason you're getting the result in MacBook is because on osx the default method is spawn to start processes (as compared to fork on linux). Because of this, any code not under the `if __name__ ...` block will be executed for *each* process. Therefore, you would be creating a different semaphore for different processes which is why all of them are acquiring/releasing at the same time since all the semaphores are only being acquired/released from one process at max (so they're not really limiting concurrency at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't know how your posted code can run at all. You have:

```py
if __name__ = "___main__": # two errors here: = -> ==, "___main__" -> "__main__"
```

i.e. this should be:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

When you are running on a platform that uses the *spawn* method to start child processes, each child process will be executing everything defined at global scope unless it is within the above `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. That means that each process will be creating and using its own semaphore. Clearly, this is a problem. You need to create the semaphore in the main process and pass it as an argument to your "worker" function, `test_print`:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def test_print(semaphore):
    with semaphore:
        print("starting!")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("ending!")


if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    concurrency = 3
    semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(concurrency)
    processList = []
    for _ in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_print, args=(semaphore,))
        p.start()
        processList.append(p)
    for p in processList:
        p.join()
```

Prints:

```
starting!
starting!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
ending!
ending!
starting!
starting!
starting!
ending!
ending!
ending!
starting!
ending!
```

**Update**

I only just now saw the comment posted by Charchit Agarwal, which is exactly what I have said.

Comment: Did this not solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, sorry there are issues in the code because I just manually typed out a MWE --- my actual task is a lot more complicated. Thanks for your comments, let me try this out later today and I'll accept your answer then.

Answer (score -1):

Your expectation is not correct. The output would be like the following:

```
starting!
starting!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
starting!
ending!
ending!
ending!
```

At first, 3 programs start simultaneously and then when each of them finished another one could be able to get the semaphore and start.

It seems you're running different codes in different machines.
You could get your mentioned results in your Server and Macbook with the following setting respectively,
`concurrency = 1`
and
`concurrency = 10`. However, it would be possible to have `p.join()` in your loop in the first case.